# Processing custom annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, metadata

Is it possible to make the [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) detects if beans classes have methods annotated with a custom annotation (@inject for instance) and proceed to make a certain treatment if it's the case ?
If this is not possible, can you explain how i get access to the beans metadata and exploit it in the BeanFactoryPostProcessor ?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I came across this [link](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/), not sure if it's the right solution though, since i heard that using reflections considerably deteriorates the overall application performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ConfigurableListableBeanFactory passed into the postProcessBeanFactory() method call, has a method getBeanDefinition(String), from which you can get the class name of that bean.  From here you can do a Class.forName(String), and get the class, and then you can inspect its members for your annotation.  Of course this suggestion uses Java Reflection also.

You could also try to annotate each class that you want to inspect with its own custom annotation.  From the ConfigurableListableBeanFactory you can then call getBeansWithAnnotation(Class).  This returns a map from beanName to the corresponding instance.

Or you can take a look at the JavaDoc yourself:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html